# Relevant coupling in RG and bound states

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

In many references, it is stated that relevant coupling in the renormalization group may give rise to bound states. For example, in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9210046.pdf) article by Polchinski, he says

> At scales below the cutoff, a super-renormalizable coupling will have a dimensionless strength much greater than unity. One would therefore expect complicated dynamics, likely with the formation
>   of bound states and condensates.

My question is: How does the relevant coupling gives rise to the bound state? Is it possible to calculate the bound state energy from the flow equations?

In case this requires a long answer, any reference to a relevant article which shows a proper calculation will be much appreciated.

Comment: It does not lead to bound states. It just allows for the possibility of bound states. A relevant coupling is an expanding direction which takes you far from the starting point. Where you end up could be (but is not necessarily) a more complicated theory with new degrees of freedom which can be seen as bound states/condensates. The typical example is BCS theory of superconductivity and the formation of Cooper pairs.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam what do you mean by "which can be seen as bound states/condensates". If we don't know what the new degrees of freedom are, how can we categorize the new state as bound state or condensate. I am fairly new to RG analysis, so please explain your answer if you can